# text file into a nested python dictionary more than one variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that is formatted as follows:

```
[one]
A = color
B = Petals
C = Junk

[two]
Z = 10
A = freq
corner = yes

[three]
D = code
status = 45
```

I'm trying to read this file into a nested dictionary so that it looks like this:

```
{'one':{'A':'color','B':'Petals','C':'Junk'},
{'two':{'Z':'10','A':'freq':'corner':'yes'},
{'three':{'D':'code','status':'45'}}
```

I tried

```
import re

ini_sections = []
ini_dict = {}
x = 0

with open(path,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        re_found = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]',line)
        re_found = ''.join(re_found)
        ini_sections.append(re_found)

        try:
            if re_found:
                next_line = next(f)
                while re.findall('=',next_line):
                    key,value = next_line.rstrip('\n').split('=')
                    ini_dict.update({ini_sections[x]:{key.strip():value.strip()}})
                    next_line = next(f)
            x +=1
        except StopIteration:
            print("EOF!")
```

Output:

```
for key, value in ini_dict.items():
    print(key, value)

>>>one {'C':'Junk'}
   two {'corner':'yes'}
   three {'status':'45'}
```

But only the last items remain in the dictionary.  Not sure why that is.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Have you tried e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a separate `ini_sections` (you create them but you don't even iterate over each of them while printing). Create *one* `ini_dict`, which will contain the three main keys `one`, `two`, and `three`, each one with a *value* of a `dict`. The current dict's name will be `re_found`; update only *that* inside your loop.

Your original code, changed here and there:

```
import re
import pprint

ini_dict = {}
x = 0

with open('test.cfg','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        re_found = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]',line)
        re_found = ''.join(re_found)
        ini_dict[re_found] = dict()

        try:
            if re_found:
                next_line = next(f)
                while re.findall('=',next_line):
                    key,value = next_line.rstrip('\n').split('=')
                    ini_dict[re_found][key.strip()] = value.strip()
                    next_line = next(f)
        except StopIteration:
            print("EOF!")

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
pp.pprint (ini_dict)
```

Result (indentation comes courtesy of [prettyprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)):

```
EOF!
{'one': {'A': 'color', 'B': 'Petals', 'C': 'Junk'},
 'three': {'D': 'code', 'status': '45'},
 'two': {'A': 'freq', 'Z': '10', 'corner': 'yes'}}
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!