# Can python read this type of config file?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, file, config

good morning. I want you help. I'm making a  project using python but i want know if python2 can read this type of config file. Example:

```
[SETTINGS]
{
  "Name": "SKY",
  "SuggestedBots": 50,
  "MaxCPM": 3000,
  "LastModified": "2019-11-03T23:24:24.0854425-03:00",
  "AdditionalInfo": "",
  "Author": "KATO",
  "Version": "1.1.4",
  "IgnoreResponseErrors": false,
  "MaxRedirects": 8,
  "NeedsProxies": true,
  "OnlySocks": false,
  "OnlySsl": false,
  "MaxProxyUses": 0,
  "BanProxyAfterGoodStatus": false,
  "EncodeData": false,
  "AllowedWordlist1": "",
  "AllowedWordlist2": "",
  "DataRules": [],
  "CustomInputs": [],
  "ForceHeadless": false,
  "AlwaysOpen": false,
  "AlwaysQuit": false,
  "DisableNotifications": false,
  "CustomUserAgent": "",
  "RandomUA": false,
  "CustomCMDArgs": ""
}
```

I tryed with tutorials from internet but doesn't work. I think it's JSON.

Comment: Where did that JSON/ini hybrid abomination come from?

Comment: the first line isn't JSON compliant, it looks like a name. If you just drop the first line of the file, the `json` builtin library should be able to take care of the rest.

Comment: Fairly similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/59831811 if you want to do it without external libraries.

Comment: Thanks guys, you help me :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drop the first line, then it can be used in python.

```
import json

test = '''{
  "Name": "SKY",
  "SuggestedBots": 50,
  "MaxCPM": 3000,
  "LastModified": "2019-11-03T23:24:24.0854425-03:00",
  "AdditionalInfo": "",
  "Author": "KATO",
  "Version": "1.1.4",
  "IgnoreResponseErrors": false,
  "MaxRedirects": 8,
  "NeedsProxies": true,
  "OnlySocks": false,
  "OnlySsl": false,
  "MaxProxyUses": 0,
  "BanProxyAfterGoodStatus": false,
  "EncodeData": false,
  "AllowedWordlist1": "",
  "AllowedWordlist2": "",
  "DataRules": [],
  "CustomInputs": [],
  "ForceHeadless": false,
  "AlwaysOpen": false,
  "AlwaysQuit": false,
  "DisableNotifications": false,
  "CustomUserAgent": "",
  "RandomUA": false,
  "CustomCMDArgs": ""
}'''

json.loads(test)

# {u'AlwaysQuit': False, u'Author': u'KATO', u'LastModified': u'2019-11-03T23:24:24.0854425-03:00', u'DataRules': [], u'AlwaysOpen': False, u'Version': u'1.1.4', u'DisableNotifications': False, u'NeedsProxies': True, u'CustomInputs': [], u'EncodeData': False, u'BanProxyAfterGoodStatus': False, u'SuggestedBots': 50, u'ForceHeadless': False, u'RandomUA': False, u'AdditionalInfo': u'', u'Name': u'SKY', u'CustomUserAgent': u'', u'MaxRedirects': 8, u'CustomCMDArgs': u'', u'OnlySocks': False, u'MaxProxyUses': 0, u'IgnoreResponseErrors': False, u'AllowedWordlist1': u'', u'AllowedWordlist2': u'', u'OnlySsl': False, u'MaxCPM': 3000}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it help me so much.